# react native undefined object

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, expo

I set a state like this:

```
const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
```

I put this object in to setAddress:

```
{"street_number":"1","street":"Wheins","city":"Denmark"}
```

I want to output the data like this:

```
address.street_number, address.street ...
```

but I got undefined. Why?

Comment: Please share the actual code that has the problem. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You example is not complete (i.e. it does not contain all relevant parts to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Additionally if `address` is supposed to be an object you shouldn't initialise it with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting the above response from a API endpoint..

Then,

```
console.log(address["street_number"]) // this will output "1"

console.log(address["street"]) // this will output "Wheins"
```

And yes for Initializing the state you should use a object,

Like this -

```
const [address, setAddress] = useState({});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use state, something like this might work, depending on your use case:

```
...
const [address, setAddress] = useState('');

setAddress({"street_number":"1","street":"Wheins","city":"Denmark"});

return (
    <>
        <p>Address: {address.street_number}, {address.street}, {address.city}</p>
    </>
);
...
```

It all depends how you're trying to use it? Which isn't in the original question. If the `setAddress` is in a callback or something it might not be available at the first render, so you might want to do something like:

```
...
const [address, setAddress] = useState(false);

setAddress({"street_number":"1","street":"Wheins","city":"Denmark"});

return (
    <>
        {address && (<p>Address: {address.street_number}, {address.street}, {address.city}</p>)}
    </>
);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to access the address-state in the same scope where you set it. But you should wait for the re-render. So this won't work:

```
setAddress({'street_number':'1', 'street':'Wheins', 'city':'Denmark'});
console.log('address.street_number:', address.street_number); // output: undefined
```

you could use the useEffect() hook to listen for changes in your state and then start using it:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    console.log(address.street_number); // output: 1

  }, [address]);
```